# MariaDB dynamic columns for activity stream?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, mariadb

I have the following problem:

We have a lot of different, yet similar types of data items that we want to record in a (MariaDB) database. All data items have some common parameters such as id, username, status, file glob, type, comments, start & end time stamps. In addition there are many (let's say between 40 and 100) parameters that are specific to each type of data item.

We would prefer to have the different data item types in the same table because they will be displayed along with several other data, as they happen, in one single list in the web application. This will appear like an activity stream or "Facebook wall".

It seems that the normalised approach with a top-level generic table joined with specific tables underneath will lead to bad performance. We will have to do both a lot of joins and unions in order to display the activity stream, and the application will frequently poll with this query, so it's important that the query runs fast.

So, which is the better solution(s) in terms of performance and storage optimization?

1. to utilize MariaDB's dynamic columns
2. to just add in all the different kinds of columns we need in one table, and just accept that each data item type will only use a few of the columns, i.e. the rest will be null.
3. something else?

Does it matter if we use regular columns when a lot of the data in them will be null?

When should we use dynamic columns and when is it better to use regular columns?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should have separate columns for the values you are filtering by. However, you might have some unfiltered values. For those it might be a good idea to store them in a single column as a json object (simple to encode/decode).

Comment: That would be similar to using MariaDB's dynamic columns, which can be extracted in json format. So basically my option 1. I'm still as confused about why one solution is better than another, though.

Comment: It always depends on the particular case. If you need to filter by a column, then you need to make it easy for filtering. If it is a data to parse, then you might make it compact.

Answer (score 1):

- A few columns -- the main ones for using in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses (but not necessarily all the columns you might filter on.
- A JSON column or MariaDB Dynamic columns.

See my blog on [why not to use EAV schema](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).  I focus on how to do it in JSON, but MariaDB's Dynamic Columns is arguably better.

Comment: Thank you - I have actually come across your blog entry on this before while looking for solutions on this topic. From a performance or storage space perspective, I'm still not sure exactly why this approach is better than just creating regular columns. Is there a performance penalty with that approach? Do null values take up space?

Comment: If there are 20 'optional' 'attributes', no problem.  If there are 200, it gets clumsy.  Tomorrow you will need 201; `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` is painful.  And it is costly and not productive to have dozens of indexes.  So, I encourage you to figure out the few columns that are _usually_ used for filtering, and limit the explicit columns and indexes to them.  (These are my opinions, after seeing a few products get really screwed up.)

Comment: I don't think the aesthetics of it is a weighty argument against explicit columns. What matters is whether there is a performance penalty or if it's wasting storage space. `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` doesn't scare me. MariaDB makes it possible to index dynamic columns, although I'm not sure if there are any disadvantages. In any case, most of the indexed columns will be explicit columns anyway. What about BLOB columns though, are there any disadvantages in terms of performance and storage?